# 403 Forbidden on lamp-server vhost

Tags: lamp, apache-2.4, drupal7

This is on my dev machine which is running Linux mint 16 (which is based on Ubuntu 13.10).  I installed lamp via:

```
apt install lamp-server^
```

and am running Apache 2.4.6

Upon installing lamp I created an info.php file to run phpinfo(); in /var/www, and of course that worked fine.  On my dev machine I like to create a ~/public_html in my users home folder. Inside there I create my vhosts folders.

then I gave the public_html folder to the www-data user:group added myuser to the www-data group, and gave users and groups rwx access with:

```
chmod -R 775 /home/myuser/public_html
```

now my public_html and children look like

```
drwxrwxr-x    5 www-data www-data  4096 Apr  1 12:10 public_html
```

now I created a /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.local.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.local
    DocumentRoot "/home/myuser/public_html/example.local.d"
    <Directory "/home/myuser/public_html/example.local.d">
            Options Includes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then ran:

```
a2ensite example.local.conf
service apache2 reload // I've also service apache2 restart
```

then going to example.local I get a 403

I have tried a few different configurations for the vhost .conf file.  In one I specified error logs

in the error.log I got:

```
[Tue Apr 01 12:13:06.375465 2014] [core:error] [pid 14208] (13)Permission denied:          [client 127.0.0.1:45489] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path     '/home/myuser/public_html') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

[Tue Apr 01 12:13:06.600588 2014] [core:error] [pid 14208] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:45489] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/home/myuser/public_html') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

How do I fix this?

P.S. This is going to be for developing a Drupal site if that helps with the answer.

Comment: if you try to setup per user directory https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/public_html.html

Comment: Thanks I didn't see that through my searching.  I'll try that once I get home.

Answer (score 3):

Your error message says:

```
because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

which means that a *parent* directory does not allow Apache to traverse it.

To find out what directory that is, use `ls -ld` on each directory in turn, or (Linux-only) [use `namei`](https://serverfault.com/a/639215/126632):

```
namei -l /home/myuser/public_html
```

You will then be shown the permissions and be able to find the directory with the permissions that need to be corrected. For example, you may see:

```
f: /home/myuser/public_html
drwxr-xr-x root   root   /
drwxr-xr-x root   root   home
drwx------ myuser myuser myuser
drwxr-xr-x myuser myuser public_html
```

In this case, `/home/myuser` does not allow directory traversal for anyone other than the user. So it would be corrected with:

```
chmod +x /home/myuser
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo chmod o+x -R /home/myuser/
sudo chmod 777 -R /home/myuser/
```

This works for me.

Comment: Any answer including `chmod 777` is doing it wrong.