# Tool to show permissions of path in Linux?

Tags: linux, permissions

Is there a tool in Linux that will take a path such as `/var/log/httpd/error_log`, and print the permission for each branch of the path, i.e.:

```
/var:                     root:root,         0755
/var/log:                 root:root,         0755
/var/log/httpd:           www-data:root,     0700
/var/log/httpd/error_log: www-data:www-data, 0644
```

Such a tool would make permission troubleshooting much easier, especially with exceptionally long paths like on file servers and such.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You want `namei`.

```
# namei -l /var/log/nginx/error.log
f: /var/log/nginx/error.log
drwxr-xr-x root  root  /
drwxr-xr-x root  root  var
drwxr-xr-x root  root  log
drwx------ nginx nginx nginx
-rw-r--r-- nginx nginx error.log
```

Note that this command is Linux-specific and may not exist on other operating systems. Also do not confuse it with the `namei()` system call.

Comment: *adds to list of handy commands*

Comment: That worked perfectly for my purposes, one "accept" and a +1 for you.