# Virtual Host on Apache 2.4 on Linux

Tags: linux, debian, virtualhost, apache-2.4, debian-jessie

I'm trying to create a virtual host that have path to user directory like this **/home/user1/dev**

My *.conf file is it **/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf**, like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite
    DocumentRoot /home/user1/dev
    ServerAlias mysite
    <Directory /home/user1/dev>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
   </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

I add group **www-data** to directory **/home/user1/dev** and **user1** belong to group **www-data** too.

Also I add to **/etc/hosts**

127.0.0.1       mysite       mysite

But I get **403 Forbidden**

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

I'm using

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Debian GNU/Linux 8.2 (jessie)
```

ls -la /home/user1/dev

```
drwxrws---  5 user1 www-data 4096 dic  2 01:53 .
drwxr-x--- 99 user1 user1   4096 dic  2 03:49 ..
-rwxrwx---  1 user1 www-data   54 feb 27  2014 index.html
-rwxrwx---  1 user1 www-data   23 dic  2 01:53 index.php
```

Any help or other suggestion to point path to user directory?

Comment: Is the symlink in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`?  What do the error logs say?

Comment: Yes symlink is in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled. error log: AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/omixam/localhost_omixam') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

Comment: Start with the proper directives for Apache 2.4, see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Comment: I did the change in my .conf file but I still having the same error.

Comment: And are the permissions on `/home/user1/` sufficiently open?

Comment: The permisions obtain with ls -la /home/user1/ are drwxr-x---

Comment: From the link posted by Federico Sierra: "You should review the Authentication, Authorization and Access Control Howto, especially the section [Beyond just authorization](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html#beyond) which explains the new mechanisms for controlling the order in which the authorization directives are applied." The config posted above doesn't look like you've made the necessary changes (hint: Allow & Order -> Require*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> search permissions are missing on a component of the path

There's your answer.  Some component of `/home/omixam/localhost_omixam` is missing `o+x` (or `g+x` if the group is `www-data`).  [Fix that](https://serverfault.com/q/639213), problem solved.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Was very helpful. I also add some details that work for me.