# Invoice Ninja Installation Possible Permissions Error?

Tags: php, apache-2.4, centos7

I recently installed a new instance of Invoice Ninja on a CentOS 7 VM, I followed the [documentation](https://invoice-ninja.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) exactly, which outlines that I should follow [this guide](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-invoice-ninja-on-centos-7/), which I did, however, I am presented with [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuiTG.jpg) (ignore the bottom image), and I have exhausted all possible ideas I could come up with.

I asked on the invoice ninja forums, and we've checked all the following, but everyone over there seems stumped as my thread over there has gone cold. See thread [here](https://www.invoiceninja.com/forums/topic/new-install-showing-whoops-looks-like-something-went-wrong/).

- /httpd/ninja has level 775 on apache:apache
- /httpd/ninja is owned by apache:apache
- apache is running as apache:apache
- selinux is permissive

I have since tried a completely new VM with a completely new install, just for sake of making sure I didn't miss something the first time, and I am getting the same error, any suggestions would be massively appreciated.

Comment: You need to check the permissions of all the parent directories. Try the [namei](https://serverfault.com/a/639215/126632) tool for this.

Comment: @MichaelHampton not sure what to do with this information, would you be able to elaborate?

Comment: You could start by adding it to your question. If you don't know what to do with it, someone else will.